# Trouble with a UISearchField when filtering a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have created a search bar in Xcode using Swift 3. I get the data through an api. However, while I search the cursor goes away. Not only that but before I put a delay in it I could only type one letter. I'm not sure if it was my code, the async or what.

So I found this article (http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/)

The problem I'm having is this portion in Swift 3:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So I used the documentation and found:

```
static var caseInsensitive: NSString.CompareOptions
```

My question is how do I interpret this? This is supposed to mean that `caseInsensitive` is type `String.CompareOptions`?

Do I stack this on options: `caseInsensitive: String.CompareOptions`?

I'm so new at this. I know python and that's about it but I love learning these new languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow at least now I understand the documentation. lol I changed it to:

```
let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
```

Comment: Even better: `let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)`